# Updating weights in magento database

Tags: php, database, magento

I am trying to mass update a few thousand products on magento and I am having some issues with getting the script I have wrote to work.  I have added a new table with a list of SKU's and the weights. I am then using this code(below) to try and go through each row and then update the weight in the magento tables.

This is the code I have, as you can see I have tried 2 different methods and it doesn't come up with errors or anything but no change is made in the database.

```
<?php
// DB Settings
$host = 'localhost';
$dbname = 'devdpbui_mgto';
$user = 'devdpbui_matt';
$pass = 'QuadRamR170';
 // Establish connection

 /*
// Select table with query
$sth = $dbh->query("
 SELECT sku,weight FROM temp_weight
");


// Set fetching mode
$sth->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 // Assign $row as your key to access Table fields
$i = 0;
 foreach ($sth as $row) :

if($i > 2){
 $sku = $row['sku'];
 $weight = $row['weight'];
 //print_r($row);
//print_r($weight);

 //MySqli Update Query
$query = "UPDATE dp_catalog_product_entity_decimal AS ped JOIN dp_eav_attribute AS ea ON  ea.entity_type_id = 10 AND ea.attribute_code = 'weight' AND ped.attribute_id = ea.attribute_id SET ped.value = ? WHERE ped.entity_id = ?";
if($statement = $dbh->prepare($query){
 print 'Success! ID of last inserted record is : ' .$statement->insert_id .'<br />'; 
}else{
    die('Error : ('. $dbh->errno .') '. $dbh->error);
}
if($statement->bind_param('is', $weight, $sku) {
     print 'Success! ID of last inserted record is : ' .$statement->insert_id     .'<br />'; 
}else{
    die('Error : ('. $dbh->errno .') '. $dbh->error);
}
//MySqli Delete Query
//$results = $mysqli->query("DELETE FROM products WHERE ID=24");

if($statement->execute()){
    print 'Success! ID of last inserted record is : ' .$statement->insert_id .'<br />'; 
}else{
    die('Error : ('. $dbh->errno .') '. $dbh->error);
} 

// $updateQtySQL = ;
 //echo $q->error;
 //$q = $dbh->prepare($updateQtySQL);
 //echo $q->error;
 //$q->execute(array($weight, $sku));
 //echo $q->error;
 //}

 $i++;


 endforeach;

$dbh = null;*/

?>
<?php


   $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);

// Select table with query
$sth = $dbh->query("
 SELECT sku,weight FROM temp_weight
");


// Set fetching mode
$sth->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 // Assign $row as your key to access Table fields
$i = 0;
 foreach ($sth as $row) :

if($i > 2){
 $sku = $row['sku'];
 $weight = $row['weight'];
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "devdpbui_matt", "QuadRamR170", "devdpbui_mgto");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
} else {
echo "ok";
  }
 /* create a prepared statement */
 if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "UPDATE dp_catalog_product_entity_decimal AS ped JOIN dp_eav_attribute AS ea ON  ea.entity_type_id = 10 AND ea.attribute_code = 'weight' AND ped.attribute_id = ea.attribute_id SET ped.value = ? WHERE ped.entity_id = ?")) {


    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "is", $weight, $sku);

    /* execute query */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);


    /* close statement */
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}

/* close connection */
mysqli_close($link);

 endforeach;

$dbh = null;
?>`
```

Comment: Some of your code seems perhaps syntactically incorrect `if($statement = $dbh->prepare($query){` for example looks like it is missing a paren- is this intentional?

Comment: Thanks, did not see them!